# Reduce[expr,vars] behavior when vars are not present

Tags: equation-solving

It is officially documented that `Reduce` should be used like `Reduce[expr,vars]`. However, I've used `Reduce[expr]` without the `vars` and it seems to work just fine.

Can I assume `Reduce[expr]` is just a shorthand for `Reduce[expr,vars]` where `vars` are all the `vars` in `expr`?

Comment: It can only solve for as many variables as there are equations. If there are more variables than equations, the ones for which it will solve is its choice. And, if there are parameters in addition to variables, it cannot distinguish between the parameters and the variables.